# What is the difference between the java.awt.Rectangle class and java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D.Double class?

Tags: java, awt

I mean, for all practical purposes, why is it defined twice in java.awt?

Comment: Please read the documentation

Answer (score 0):

`Rectangle2D.Double` allows you define rectangles with floating point dimensions. `Rectangle` doesn't. Additionally, you have to understand that Rectangle was retrofitted to be a subclass of `Rectangle2D` its class definition was *changed* to extend `Rectangle2D` so that (a) It could be abstracted to this new parent class, and (b) It could use all the methods in the more general Rectangle2D

Comment: Well, that goes without saying but is this the only purpose of having two rectangle classes?

Comment: @BloodBrother Edited my answer with more justification

Answer (score 0):

Rectangle2D.Double supports `double` to be specified as x, y, width and height.

Rectangle only allows `int`.

That is clearly stated in the documentation:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.Double.html

One reason for that may be that AWT is mainly used for UI and since you are operating on screen coordinates and pixels decimal values are sometimes better omitted. The general Geometry on the other hand should still support floating point rectangles. But that is just a guess...